# Clicking on the button crashes the TK window

Tags: python, tkinter, time, pyautogui, tkinter-entry

```py
import time
from tkinter import *

import pyautogui

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x200')

def button_command():
    text = int (entry1.get())

    time.sleep(3)

    pyautogui.keyDown("w")
    time.sleep(text)
    pyautogui.keyUp("w")

    return None

entry1 = Entry(root, width= 20)
entry1.pack()

Button(root,text="Button", command=button_command).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "crash"?  If there's an error message, we need to see the entire text of it.  If it's just locking up your window for the duration, that's because you *told* it to lock up for the duration.  If it's simply not doing anything useful, that's likely because the 'w' keypress is going to your Tkinter window (which necessarily has the keyboard focus, because you just clicked in it to activate the button).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Your button code is odd, I think it's best practice this way:

`button = Button(root, text='Button', command=lambda: button_command())`

`button.pack()`

That's how I use them and it's always worked seamlessly.

Comment: `command=lambda: func(...)` is only needed if the function requires parameters.  `command=func` is just fine for a function with no parameters, as is the case here.

Comment: now it says     button = Button(root, text='Button', command=lambda: add_data())
NameError: name 'add_data' is not defined

Comment: No, instead of add_data() just use the name of your function, button_command(). I got that snippet from a code of my own and forgot to change the function name. My bad. I edited the post now.

Comment: The use of `lambda` is what would be odd. `command` takes a callable, and `button_command` is a callable. `lambda` in this case adds complexity without adding value.